# Flattening of json file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I am having problems while converting the json file to the dataframe. The json file structure is like this:

```json
"results": [
    {
      "submissions": [
        {
          "submission_type": "SUPPL",
          "submission_number": "26",
          "submission_status": "AP",
          "submission_status_date": "20110902",
          "submission_class_code": "LABELING",
          "submission_class_code_description": "Labeling",
          "application_docs": [
            {
              "id": "39507",
              "url": "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/label/2011/076175s026lbl.pdf",
              "date": "20120516",
              "type": "Label"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "submission_type": "SUPPL",
          "submission_number": "30",
          "submission_status": "AP",
          "submission_status_date": "20130726",
          "review_priority": "STANDARD",
          "submission_class_code": "LABELING",
          "submission_class_code_description": "Labeling",
          "application_docs": [
            {
              "id": "39508",
              "url": "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/label/2013/076175s030lbl.pdf",
              "date": "20130729",
              "type": "Label"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "submission_type": "ORIG",
          "submission_number": "1",
          "submission_status": "AP",
          "submission_status_date": "20020220",
          "application_docs": [
            {
              "id": "18441",
              "url": "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/label/2002/76175_Mefloquine Hydrochloride_Prntlbl.pdf",
              "date": "20031224",
              "type": "Label"
            },
            {
              "id": "22542",
              "url": "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/anda/2002/076175_mefloquine_toc.cfm",
              "date": "20030804",
              "type": "Review"
            },
            {
              "id": "31095",
              "url": "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/appletter/2002/76175.ap.pdf",
              "date": "20030411",
              "type": "Letter"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
     
      ],
      "application_number": "ANDA076175",
      "sponsor_name": "SANDOZ",`your text`
      "products": [
        {
          "product_number": "001",
          "reference_drug": "No",
          "brand_name": "MEFLOQUINE HYDROCHLORIDE",
          "active_ingredients": [
            {
              "name": "MEFLOQUINE HYDROCHLORIDE",
              "strength": "250MG"
            }
          ],
          "reference_standard": "No",
          "dosage_form": "TABLET",
          "route": "ORAL",
          "marketing_status": "Discontinued"
        }
      ]
    },
```

So far the code I wrote is :

```
   **df_flattened = pd.json_normalize(data=rawData['results'])

     df_flattened.tail()**
```

then to further normalise the data I am trying to do it on submissions and product colum :

```
**df_submissions = pd.json_normalize(rawData, record_path = rawData['results']['submissions'], meta = ['application_name', 'sponsor_name'])
```

df_submissions.head()**

but I am getting error saying:

**TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df_submissions = pd.json_normalize(rawData, record_path = rawData['results']['submissions'], meta = ['application_name', 'sponsor_name'])
2 df_submissions.head()
3
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

I am not able to convert the nested list of dictionaries in submissions and products. submission column and  product column are nested list with dictionaries json_normalize doesn't work with them. I tried using it but was getting error. How can I convert this json file in to dataframe?

Any input on this will be helpful

Comment: Please don't post images of code. They are hard to work with and at some level you are asking people to retype your code from scratch in order to try to help you. Can you indicate what you hope as the final results from having loaded this json?  Have you experimented with the `json_normalize()` parameters `record_path` and `meta`?

Comment: Dear Jon, sorry I am new to it so I keep in mind. I am not asking to retype everything. I want to know if there is a way I flatenned the data in submissions ad product column. I used record_path and meta but it did not work. I was getting error "list indices should be integer not str" I suspect it because the submissions and products are list of dictinaries and hence the error. I want a way so that I can further flatten these columns in to the data frame. Thank you!

Comment: No worries :-) Can you edit the question and paste your code into a code block for us?

Answer (score 0):

I come to know across this library which reduces a lots of code and flatten the nested json objects to lowest level and make separated columns. For more information click [here](https://pypi.org/project/flatten-json/).

```
#https://pypi.org/project/flatten-json/
from flatten_json import flatten
with open('.\\Results.Json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

print(data)

dic_flattened = [flatten(d) for d in data['results']]     
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)

print(df)
```

Output:

[image]